# Uploading video thumbnail not getting in mediawiki file page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am new to mediawiki, I downloaded the latest version and installed in my local linux server(/var/www/mediawiki-1.23.2). After configured i got the localsettings.php and put the file in mediawiki, And I run the mediawiki, And i tried to upload a file using(Special:Upload).I uploaded the video file like(value.ogg), the video has uploaded but after check the file in "File:value.ogg" the videofile does'nt show with the poster image and In file history also not getting the thumbnail but the thumbnail is  getting in image upload. whether i need to add any other assumption in localsettings.php file to get the uploaded video image as well as with the mwembed player. Kindly suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki doesn't render files, each file type needs its rendering set up. For videos and ogg videos in particular, you must install TimedMediaHandler (formerly known as OggHandler). https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TimedMediaHandler

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you may have seen a link and went straight to "link-only answer" mode. To me, it looks more like a brief answer (installing X to solve this problem) followed by a link (and you can get X here).

Comment: A lot more information should be provided, including how installing that will solve the problem, how to use the library once installed, etc.. Simply saying "use library X" does not provide a complete answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Mike, this is not a library, it's a plugin. Once installed, there is nothing to do. I've expanded the answer as requested.